# How to re-sort information within a table/ compress information within a table

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I´m working with RStudio

So I'm wondering how to use the data typed in below:

Current Table:

```
Value.  Biotop  
1. Forest Coniferous
2. Soil Type
3. Urban Green Areas
4. Buildings/Urban Area
5. Forest Coniferous
6. Forest Coniferous
7. Forest Coniferous
8. Forest Coniferous
9. Forest Coniferous
10. Forest Coniferous
11. Forest Coniferous
12. Forest Coniferous
13. Soil Type
14. Forest Coniferous
15. Forest Coniferous
16. Forest Coniferous
17. Forest Coniferous
18. Soil Type
19. Soil Type
20. Soil Type
21. Soil Type
22. Soil Type
23. Soil Type
24. Soil Type
25. Urban Green Areas
26. Urban Green Areas
27. Urban Green Areas
28. Urban Green Areas
29. Urban Green Areas
30. Urban Green Areas
31. Urban Green Areas
```

To re-sort my data into something more like this:

Future Table:

```
Value. Biotop
.1. Forest Coniferous
.2. Soil type.
.3. Urban Green Area
.4. Buildings/Urban Area
.5. -- 12. Forest Coniferous
.13. Soil Type
.14. -- 17. Forest Coniferous
.18. -- 24. Soil Type 
.25. -- 31. Urban Green Areas
```

Sorry for lack of good visualisation, I'm (as you probably can see) new to this. They are in any case meant to depict tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With package `data.table` you can achieve this in an one-liner (kind of):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, .(Value = paste(unique(range(Value)), collapse = "-"), 
       Biotop = Biotop[1]), by = rleid(Biotop)][, rleid := NULL][]
```

which returns

```
#   Value               Biotop
#1:     1    Forest Coniferous
#2:     2            Soil Type
#3:     3    Urban Green Areas
#4:     4 Buildings/Urban Area
#5:  5-12    Forest Coniferous
#6:    13            Soil Type
#7: 14-17    Forest Coniferous
#8: 18-24            Soil Type
#9: 25-31    Urban Green Areas
```

### Explanation

`setDT()` ensures that `dt` is of class `data.table` if it's not already. Then, we create an index for contiguous streaks of `Biotop` and group by this index. For each group, the lowest and highest `Value` is taken (using the `range()` function) and pasted into a string of the form `14-17`, e.g. To avoid cases like `13-13` we use `unique` which collapses the string to `13`. Finally, we remove the index which was only required for grouping.

Note, this assumes that `Value` is ordered within each group so we can take the lowest and highest `Value` for the first and last entry.

### Data

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("Value.  Biotop  
            1. Forest Coniferous
            2. Soil Type
            3. Urban Green Areas
            4. Buildings/Urban Area
            5. Forest Coniferous
            6. Forest Coniferous
            7. Forest Coniferous
            8. Forest Coniferous
            9. Forest Coniferous
            10. Forest Coniferous
            11. Forest Coniferous
            12. Forest Coniferous
            13. Soil Type
            14. Forest Coniferous
            15. Forest Coniferous
            16. Forest Coniferous
            17. Forest Coniferous
            18. Soil Type
            19. Soil Type
            20. Soil Type
            21. Soil Type
            22. Soil Type
            23. Soil Type
            24. Soil Type
            25. Urban Green Areas
            26. Urban Green Areas
            27. Urban Green Areas
            28. Urban Green Areas
            29. Urban Green Areas
            30. Urban Green Areas
            31. Urban Green Areas", sep =".")
```

Comment: Thanks, although when I run it as you suggest this is the error message I get: Error in [.tbl_df(df, , .(Value = paste(unique(range(Value)), : unused argument (by = rleid(Biotop))

Comment: I've added a `setDT()` to the code to make sure that is a `data.table`.

Comment: @Nedim: I'm sorry I wasn't aware in which form you had stored your data because this information was missing from your Q. (For the next time, please add the output of `dput(...)` or at least `str(...)` to your Q). From the error message I can see that you have stored your data as `tibble` which needs to be converted to `data.table` (using `setDT()`) to make the one-liner work.

Comment: This time it worked perfectly, I will try to be more specific as to the conditions of my questions in the future. Thank you.